# get maximum value by stack in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
                                correlation
       total_acc    num_sats    0.715618
                    open_acc    0.717911
percent_bc_gt_75    revol_util  0.739611
     num_bc_sats    num_bc_tl   0.74768
```

These are values I got after unstacking correlation between my columns
with the first and second columns being index, for those index with two or more correlation values for instance the first one, I want to get the maximum and drop the rest in the row which in this case, the first row would be `total_acc  open_acc   0.717911` only. I will really appreciate any help I have not written any code to try n do this coz the logic is not hitting me

my dataframe is called `df`

Comment: Please write as correct English as you can. English is not the first language for many of us, so you should try to help us to help you.

Comment: I made some few changes I hope you can understand now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `groupby` first level of index, and then get the index of the max of correlation per group:

```
df.loc[df.groupby(level=0)['correlation'].agg('idxmax')]
```

gives as expected:

```
                             correlation
num_bc_sats      num_bc_tl      0.747680
percent_bc_gt_75 revol_util     0.739611
total_acc        open_acc       0.717911
```

Comment: best!! exactly want I wanted but could not even frame it well